# where should I add another await for asyncio to work correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm downloading all the images from pexels.com with a given keywork by the user. The program gives me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./asyncioPexels.py", line 73, in <module>
asyncio.run(forming_all_pages(numberOfPages, mainurl))
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "./asyncioPexels.py", line 50, in forming_all_pages
await download_all_pages(urls)
File "./asyncioPexels.py", line 38, in download_all_pages
async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

I think the problem now is that I'm using the function `download_all_pages` as a context manager! If this is the problem, how should I fix it? I have a general idea to make it work as a context manager or there is an easier solution?
here goes my whole code:

```
async def download_single_image(subsession, imgurl):
    print(f'Downloading img {imgurl}')
    async with session.get(imgurl) as res:
        imgFile = open(os.path.join(str(keyword), os.path.basename(imgurl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imgFile.write(chunk)
        imgFile.close()

async def download_all_images(imgurls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession as subsession:
        subtasks = []
        for imgurl in imgurls:
            subtask = asyncio.ensure_future(download_single_image(subsession, imgurl))
            subtasks.append(subtask)
        await asyncio.gather(*subtasks, return_exception=True)

async def download_single_page(session, url):
    print(f'Downloading page {url}...')
    imgurls = []
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        imgs = response.text.split('infiniteScrollingAppender.append')[1:]
        for img in imgs:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(img[2:-5].replace("\\'", "'").replace('\\"', '"'), 'html.parser')
            imgurls.append(soup.select('.photo-item__img')[0].get('srcset'))
        await download_all_images(imgurls)

async def download_all_pages(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(download_single_page(session, url))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exception=True)

async def forming_all_pages(numberOfPages, mainurl):
    urls = []
    for _ in range(1, numberOfPages + 1):
        page = mainurl + str(_)
        urls.append(page)
    await download_all_pages(urls)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(forming_all_pages(numberOfPages, mainurl))
```

How to solve this problem for the code to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `forming_all_pages` you have

```
download_all_pages(urls)
```

But as the exception tells you

```
./asyncioPexels.py:50: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'download_all_pages' was never awaited
```

Change this to

```
await download_all_pages(urls)
```

You also need to change `download_single_page` to use

```
await download_all_images(imgurls)
```

Finally, `forming_all_pages` needs to be awaitable. You need to change it to

```
async def forming_all_pages(numberOfPages, mainurl):
```

Comment: still giving me the exact same error, nothing changed at all even after adding await @dirn

Comment: Sorry, I referenced the wrong one and it looks like you had two such problems. I've updated the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I changed it and now getting different error, I updated my code. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: You need parentheses after `ClientSession`.